# need something like event.target.focus() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, focus, onchange

I'm creating a dynamic list component that basically renders a new empty text field every time something is added to the list. The component is as follows (it uses a custom TextFieldGroup but I don't think that code is necessary as nothing out of the ordinary is going on.):

```
const DynamicInputList = ({ inputs, onChangeArray, label, name, errors }) => 
{
  const nonEmptyInputs = inputs.filter(input => {
    return input !== "";
  });
  const lastIndex = nonEmptyInputs.length;
  return (
    <div>
      {nonEmptyInputs.map((input, index) => {
        return (
          <Grid container spacing={16} key={index}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextFieldGroup
                label={label}
                id={`${name}${index}`}
                name={name}
                value={input}
                onChange={e => onChangeArray(e, index)}
                errors={errors[name]}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
      <Grid container spacing={16} key={lastIndex}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextFieldGroup
            label={label}
            id={`${name}${lastIndex}`} 
            name={name}
            value={inputs[lastIndex]}
            onChange={e => onChangeArray(e, lastIndex)}
            errors={errors[name]}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The onChangeArray function is as follows:

```
  onChangeArray = (e, index) => {
    const state = this.state[e.target.name];
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      state.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: state });
    } else {
      state.splice(index, 1, e.target.value);
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: state });
    }
  };
```

Everything works fine except when a blank field is changed (begin to type) it immediately removes focus from any of the fields. I'm looking for a way to keep the focus on this field while still adding the new one below.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please elaborate it.. Everything works fine except when a blank field is changed (begin to type) it immediately removes focus from any of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're encountering the following sequence of events (assuming `inputs` length of 5):

1. React renders 1 field (key = 5)
2. User starts typing 'a'
3. Your state change is triggered
4. React renders 2 entirely new fields (key = 1 & value = 'a', key = 5)  and trashes the old one (key = 5)

There are at least two solutions

### Don't delete / trigger re-render of the original field

This is the cleaner solution.

First, you are directly mutating state in `onChangeArray` with your use of `slice`, because [that does an in-place modification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Perhaps this isn't causing problems now, but it's a big React anti-pattern and could create unpredictable behavior.

Here's a quick fix:

```js
  onChangeArray = (e, index) => {
    const state = [...this.state[e.target.name]];
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      state.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: state });
    } else {
      state.splice(index, 1, e.target.value);
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: state });
    }
  };
```

[And other options](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5)

I'll leave the reworking of the implementation to you, but the gist would be:

1. Use consistent `key` references, which means iterate over all your `inputs` and just skip the empty ones instead of finding the empty ones first and setting that arbitrary key to the total length. Of course, you should still render the *first* empty one.
2. You could consider rendering everything, and use CSS `display:none` attribute as needed to accomplish your desired UX

### Leverage `input`'s `autofocus` attribute

I assume your `TextFieldGroup` uses an `input` element. You could pass the [`autofocus` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) to the field you want to have focus. This answers your original question.

But this isn't recommended, as you're still needlessly running through those re-render cycles and then putting a patch on top.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually should have known to use the spread operator (...) but I'm still new to all this, thanks for catching that. To solve my problem I basically delete the empty fields in the onChangeArray function now instead of inside the component by filtering the copied state (i.e. newState = state.filter(item => item !== "")). I also add the last field by updating state with this.setState({[e.target.name]: [...newState, ""]}). That way my component uses consistent key references as you mentioned. Hope this is closer to a React-like pattern.